# Replace text with an image if font not available

Tags: javascript, image, replace, font-face

I have a web page which uses a non-web-safe font (@font-face...) for a header.

This is going to look pretty bad if the viewer's browser does not support this, so is there a way to detect this capability and replace the text with an image if it is not supported?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'awesomefont';
    src: url('fonts/awesomefont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/awesomefont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/awesomefont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/awesomefont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/awesomefont-webfont.svg#awesomefont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'awesomefont'; /* Substitute with image if font not supported */
}

p {
    font-family: 'awesomefont', Arial, sans-serif; /* main body text can use alternative font */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nosifer Caps';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nosifer Caps Regular'), local('NosiferCaps-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/nosifercaps/v1/5Vh3eVJZ2pCbwAqfFmh1F3hCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff') format('woff');
}

p {
  font-family: 'Nosifer Caps', cursive; // is this not the point of defining a websafe font after your non-websafe-font????
}
```

or do you want to ALWAYS have said font for your header.. in which case I wouldn't even go through the hassle of dealing with custom fonts. Just create your image and use that 100% of the time. The overhead of loading an entire font lib for one header image is just silly.

Comment: I am using the font throughout the website so the loading overhead is not an issue. For the main body text of the site I have defined a web-safe font, but on the page header should be replaced with an image rather than an alternative font if possible.

Comment: Ok, I have to ask. How large is your header? and if you don't mind me asking what font are you using? have you compared the weight of just making the header a static image? It may not be that much. Also consider, if you are concerned about size; any of these solutions will ultimately add more size to the page, and more processing power by the client. I will once again emphasis that if you are hell bent on not using a websafe font as a backup, stick to a static image as your #1 option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you're asking. But I generally use cufon for using custom fonts on my websites. It uses canvas to create an image from the text. If a browser does not support javascript, it simply displays the raw text

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use one of the JS libraries which measure the width of the string to detect if the font is available. Unfortunately, functionality is not available in JS to do what you want directly.

Here are some implementations which use the string measurement technique:

- http://derek1906.site50.net/works/jfont.php
- http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/